# Как сделать, чтоб пустое сообщение не отправлялось?

Tags: php

У меня есть чат, как сделать, чтоб пустое сообщение не отправлялось? Я знаю, что это делается через if.

Вот сам чат:

```
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400"></iframe>
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" name="form" target='chatWindow' >
<p>Сообщение:<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
```

А это iframe:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
      $message = $_POST['message'];
  }

  $db = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***");
  mysql_select_db("***", $db);
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('$message')");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "{$row['message']}";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Кода, отвечающего за отправку (прием формы) в приведенных фрагментах нет.

Comment: Я же говорю - странный перец... и ни одного "принятого" - обратите внимание! :)

Comment: Я не прошу вас комментировать, а прошу помочь исправить ошибки. )))

Comment: Еще опечатка: `maxlenght` вместо `maxlength`.
Ну и `</form>` не закрыт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать проверку на стороне клиента, что-то такое:

```
<script>
    // Requires jQuery 1.6+
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#form").onsubmit(function (event) {
            var message = $("input[name='message']", form).value()
            if (message) { event.preventDefault(); return false; }
            return true;
        });
        $("#form input[name='message']").bind(
            'change keydown keypress',
            function(event) {
                var text = $(this).value().replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
                $("#form input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", text == "");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

При этом форме вместо `name="form"` прописать `id="form"`.

Но это не решение проблемы, т.к. клиенту доверять нельзя и проверку нужно сделать и на сервере (а проверка на клиенте — чисто эстетика).

Со стороны сервера:

```
<?php
  $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : "";

  $db = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***");
  mysql_select_db("***", $db);
  if (trim($message) != "") {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "')");
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY time_sent ASC");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['message'];
  }
?>
```

(Добавьте колонку `time_sent` типа `TIMESTAMP`, чтобы сортировать по времени сообщения. `ASC` или `DESC` — по вкусу.)